# String array to notepad

Tags: c#

I have a string array in C# and I intend to copy it in a notepad so that each row would be located in a line. What should I do?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking.  Are you wondering how to print each element of a string array on its own line, or what...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create one string with each element on separate lines like this:

```
string[] array = { "a", "b", "c" };
string lines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array);
```

Then you can use the Clipboard class to copy the string to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText method to store a text on the clipboard. It will then be available for other applications, like notepad, to be pasted in.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this? (Depends on what you mean copy to a notepad)

```
string output = "";

foreach(string s in yourArray)
{
output += s + "\n";
}
```

(Combine this with what Rune said, above... or below depending on rating)

Comment: wouldn't String.Join() make more sense?

Comment: it's more elegant, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

- **[Reading and Writing Text Files](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx)**

If I understand you correctly, you just want to write to a text file.

1. You'll need to iterate through your string array and then write the contents of each index in the string array to a new line in the file.
2. Don't forget to properly dispose of the writer once finished with.

If you need more info, then please let me know and I will post an example, but I think it's worth giving it a go first and see how you get on :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string filepath = "some_path_in_here";
string filename = "test.txt";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false);

for(int i = 0; i < strings_array.Count; i++)
{
sw.Write(strings_array[i]);
sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
}
```

try this, but you'd better read some book, to do simple things like this one.
Don't expect others give you the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuilder to join strings to each other(if you just want to put each line in a new line):

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
foreach(string line in lines)
{
sb.AppendLine(line);
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Since string is an immutable object (if it's changed a new instance will be created) it's not recommended to do something like:

```
line=line+"\n\r";
```